# Dragonfly set original filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

I'm using Dropbox with Dragonfly to store my file uploads.

I have the following code:

```
if hash[:file_dropbox].present? #DROPBOX
    path = "Attachments/" + Time.now.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M") + "_" + rand(1000).to_s + "_" + File.basename(hash[:file_dropbox])
    data = open(hash[:file_dropbox]) { |f| f.read }
    file["file"] = Dragonfly[:images].store(data, path: path)
end
```

**Problem:**

Dragonfly uses the filename I use for path as name for storing. Is it possible to set a different separate filename when using `Dragonfly.store`?

With normal files Dragonfly uses `original_filename`, but I cannot seem to set this via `Dragonfly.store`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT1:**

I've tried the following:

```
file["file"] = Dragonfly[:images].store(data, path: path,
        original_filename: "hello.docx")

file["original_filename"] = File.basename(hash[:file_dropbox])
```

When using normal file upload, the `original_filename` can be set. But I can't set `data.original_filename` because it's just binary data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your setup, but I have model Photo and dragonfly attachment is set as image. In my case, it works like that:

```
photo.image.meta["name"] = "new_file_name.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used Dragonfly but I was going through their source code and i think passing a name option might work. Please have a look at [Github repo](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/content.rb#L68-L70%20[GitHub%20Link])

```
def name
  meta["name"] || temp_object.original_filename
end
```

Comment: Not really working since I'm using to set plain data. Please notice edit 1 for what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

In your Model class using DragonFly, add an accessor for your image:

```
dragonfly_accessor :image do
  storage_options{|attachment| {path: "<somehow generate your path>"}
end
```